# Erro ao importar Json Dinâmico via AngularJs

Tags: json, angularjs

Olá, estou tendo dificuldade em importar este Json e outros, não sei o que eu posso estar fazendo de errado nisso...

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('heroisCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
       $http.get("https://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=herois&name=Super%20Hero")
       .success(function(data) { $scope.names = data;});
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="heroisCtrl">
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.greeting }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aparece esse erro no console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=herois&name=Super%20Hero. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que você está misturando algumas coisas da documentação do Angular, vou tentar explicar os problemas:

1. Essa url que você está usando retorna JSONP para contornar a política de restrição de acesso a outro domínio. Para receber dados nesse formato, é preciso usar o método [`$http.jsonp`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) em vez de `$http.get`.
2. Segundo a documentação desse método, o parâmetro `callback` da url precisa ter o valor `JSON_CALLBACK`, e não `herois` como você está usando. Senão o Angular não vai saber tratar o resultado (se quiser manter do seu jeito, precisaria ter uma função `herois` que tratasse o resultado).
3. Os dados retornados por essa URL vêm assim:

   ```
   {"name":"Super Hero","salutation":"Dia Duit","greeting":"Dia Duit Super Hero!"}
   ```

   Ou seja, é um objeto, não uma array. Mas o código da sua view está tratando como se fosse uma array de objetos, que criaria uma linha na tabela para cada objeto com o `ng-repeat`. Isso não vai funcionar com esses dados, você precisaria eliminar o repeat e pegar as propriedades diretamente do objeto.

Corrigindo esses problemas, seu código ficaria assim:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('heroisCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
       $http.jsonp("https://angularjs.org/greet.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&name=Super%20Hero")
       .success(function(data) { $scope.dados = data;});
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="heroisCtrl">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ dados.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ dados.greeting }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Seguindo essa lógica então e compreendendo as correções em função da documentação do Angular para este caso, qual o motivo de eu não conseguir fazer o mesmo do exemplo acima com outra api?

http://www.folhacar.com.br/frontendnovo.php/api/listMarcas?callback=JSON_CALLBACK  por exemplo. Tentei imprimir como {{ dados.nome_marca }} mas nao printa nada.

Comment: Você quer dizer buscando os dados de outra API? Pode ser que ela não esteja retornando JSONP. E pode ser que ela não permita o acesso com `$http.get` (se for esse o caso, aparece um erro no console do browser, verifique isso).

Comment: Se eu uso .get retorna 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' realmente, mas se eu uso o JPONP como vc me orientou ele nao apresenta nenhum erro, porem nao printa nada, tanto na pagina quanto no console. Enfim... meu raciocínio sobre buscar em outra api e imprimir como {{dados.campo}} ta certo entao? Se for isso precisarei entrar com contato com os desenvolvedores do backend da empresa e dizer sobre essas questões.

Comment: Se a API não oferece resultado em JSONP, não adianta tentar usar JSONP. Uma opção é criar um proxy usando alguma linguagem de servidor (por exemplo, com PHP e cURL), e acessar por ajax seu próprio script, que por sua vez acessa a API.

Comment: Otimo! Muito obrigado @bfavaretto ! Foi muito útil!